# How To Swap Divs Smoothly In Raphael SVG Map

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, raphael

I have an SVG map of the U.S. generated by Raphael.js. When you click a state, the div containing the map should fade out and be replaced by a div containing information on the state. A link in the div containing the state information should bring back the map containing the div. My problem is figuring out the best method for toggling back to the map and the 50 state divs. Here is the HTML with the script I am using to return to the map:

```
<div id="map-container">
   <div id="map"></div>
</div>

<div class="state" id="alabama">
   <a href="#" class="return">Go Back To Map</a>
   <p>Some Content</p?
</div>
<div class="state" id="alaska">
   <a href="#" class="return">Go Back To Map</a>
   <p>Some Content</p?
</div>
<div class="state" id="arizona">
   <a href="#" class="return">Go Back To Map</a>
   <p>Some Content</p?
</div>
... every other state

<script>
$(".return").click(function() {
  $(".state#" + callMe).fadeOut(500).hide(1000);
  $("#usmap").show(1000).fadeIn(500);
 });
</script>
```

Here is the function that is in the Raphael javascript to control the state that is swapped in.

```
.click(function(){
  document.location.hash = arr[this.id];
  callMe = area[arr[this.id]].name;
    $("#usmap").first().fadeOut(500).hide(1000, function showState() {
  $(this).next(".state#" + callMe).show(1000).fadeIn(500, showState);
});
  return false;
})
```

This is functional but the animation is not what I am looking for. The divs are shifty and move surrounding content around. I have a feeling there is a cleaner way to do this so that the divs replace each other smoothly.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I would put all 50 state map divs in one container div and fade its transparency to 0. This would be less work for the browser, since it only has to animate one div. Making it transparent instead of hiding it (which sets display: none) means it will still take up space on the page so that other content doesn't move around.

Answer (score 0):

It would be an easier task to manipulate the SVG DOM with a good JavaScript library which was built for this purpose
jQuery can do wonderful things with the DOM but should not be used in conjunction with Maps. It maybe that you need to redesign?
Would you consider having the State info in a Div under th Raphael drawn State boundaries. As the user hovers the state the opacity animates to zero revealing the State info?
It would be foolish to consider this was within your specification
Go have a look at the below 2 demos maybe this might help?

www.irunmywebsite.com/jQuery/additionaljQHelp.php?q=animation.faq3j

www.irunmywebsite.com/jQuery/additionaljQHelp.php?q=animation.faq3r

Hope it helped and was relevant.